# From cygwin, how do you define an alias to get to windows "My Documents"

Tags: bash, microsoft-word, cygwin

From the command line, I can get to My Documents by "cd /cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/myusername/My\ Documents". The space in the file name must be preceded by a backslash. However when I define an alias (myfiles) in my .bashrc file, source the .bashrc file and then type "cd $myfiles", cygwin says "too many arguments". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to quote the variable?

```
cd "$myfiles"
```

Comment: No, I had not tried using cd "$myfiles" but it works like a champ. Thanks ever so much for the suggestion.

Comment: I just discovered that single quotes around $myfiles will not work; you have to use double quotes.

Comment: @BenBlackwell I think shells usually dont interpolate variables in single quotes. Try `echo '$myfiles'`  or `echo '$HOME'` vs `echo "$HOME"`